# Errors when trying to generate a list from input that's converted to an integer and stored in a dictionary to return a message

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, input

The first piece of code works great to make a user input dictionary. In the code below and after that I try to make a list that includes only the users whose age is under 20 years old from out of the input dictionary to return a message that references their name to say "[name] is under 20 years old."

```
#Make a dictionary for 5 users' input

user_info = {}
for i in range(5):
    name, user_info[name] = input('Enter name: '), int(input('Enter age: '))
print(user_info)
```

Here's where I'm hung up. I keep getting:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`
I'm trying to iterate through the list of keys and separate out the data I want from that I don't need.

```
#Print a message for all users under age 20
under_users = []
for user_info[name] in user_info:
    if user_info[name]< 20:
        under_users.append(user_info[name])
        continue
    else:
        break
    print(f"{name} is younger than 20 years old.")
```

I am still learning how to apply while loops. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse through the dictionary. Don't use the dictionary itself to traverse. Use a separate variable like i.

```
for i in user_info: 

    if user_info[i]< 20:
 
      print(f"{i} is younger than 20 years old.")
```

If you need to make a list. You can still do that.

When you are traversing through a dictionary, you are accessing its key. In your case, name of the person is key itself. And when u pass that key to dictionary, you get to access the value. In your case the age is the value itself.

Note that i is the key in my code. I am using it to traverse the dictionary.    And user_info[i] is the value I get after passing the key i to the dictionary user_info.

Dictionary class has an inbuilt method items(). This method produces an iterable object which can be traversed using two variables to acces both key and value at the same time.

```
for key, value in user_info.items():
    if value < 20:
        print(f"{key} is younger than 20 years old.")
```

If u don't like passing the key to the dictionary again & again!

There's a pythonic way of doing this:

```
 print(*[f'{key} is younger than 20 years old' for key, value in user_info.items() if value < 20], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for these insights. This code works! I have recorded your explanation for further reflection and study. Thanks again for your time and consideration. Your explanations are a big help.

Comment: See I've edited the answer to add some more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a string and an integer. If I ask you, which is greater, 100 or 50? You'll obviously answer 100.

But if I ask you, which is greater, "Hello World!" or 127, what will you say?
Check whether the age is less than 20, you can't check whether the name is less than 20.

```
#Make a dictionary for 5 users' input
infos = []
for i in range(5):
    inputs = {"name": input("Name:"), "age": input("Age: ")}
    infos.append(inputs)
```

```
#Print a message for all users under age 20
under_users = []
for i in infos:
    if i["age"] < 20:
        under_users.append(i["name"])
print("The people under 20 are:")
print(under_users)
```

Also, in your second loop, you ran `break` under the else block. So if somebody would have been more than 20, it would stop checking and other people younger than 20 would have been ignored.

Read these:

[Dictionaries in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

[Break statements in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-break-statement/)

[Python control flow tools](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: This makes sense. However, I am trying to change my code accordingly. When I run the above code as is it tells me that "age is not defined." The thing that may be confusing is that "user_info[name]" in the dictionary is the key to the age value, and the one that is simply "name" is the key to the users' name in the dictionary. I apologize for the confusion. Thank you for your input nevertheless.

Comment: Oh, I understood now. I fixed my code and it should run properly now. I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
under_users = []
for name, age in list(user_info.items()):
    if age < 20:
        under_users.append(name)
        print(f"{name} is younger than 20 years old.")
```

The problem with your code are the following.

1. `for user_info[name] in user_info` - If `user_info = {"Anne": 25, "Bob":3}`, then the first time you enter the loop, `user_info[name]`
   becomes the first key of the dictionary, i.e. `user_info[name] = 'Anne'` So in the if-condition, you are comparing 'Anne' to 20.
2. Next is that if you `break` at `else`, the first time you encounter
   someone aged >= 20, you will exit the loop without going through the
   rest of the dictionary. So you do not need the `else`.
3. Lastly, the `print(f"{name} is younger than 20 years old.")` will
   need to be nested under the `if age < 20`. Otherwise you will print
   just the age of the last person in the dict. On that note, you do
   not need the `continue` there because no code after the `continue`
   will be executed for that iteration of the loop and the even without
   the `continue`, the loop will continue as long as the condition is
   true, which in this case means that as long as there are elements in
   `user_info`.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the quality of your response. This is immensely helpful. Thank you for taking the time and giving me such an insightful answer. Blessings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply a **string** as a **index** in python.

When you do user_info[name] you mean "name"

Instead do dictionary..items() functions to get key and value of each index.
See what we'll do here is we'll take each pair in the dictionary into **key** and **value** variables and then used them to operate over them

```
user_info = {}
for i in range(0,5):
    name, user_info[name] = input('Enter name: '), int(input('Enter age: '))

print(user_info)

under_users = []

for key,value in user_info.items():
    if user_info[key]< 20:
        under_users.append(user_info[key])
        continue
    else:
         print(f"{key} is younger than 20 years old.")

print(under_users)
```

Comment: I appreciate your insights, and the answer. Unfortunately, when I run the code, it returns the reverse of what I want. By this I mean it returns a message for all values over 20 saying those users are under 20, and doesn't reference the inputs under 20. Thank you for your input nevertheless

Comment: Yes. Because in the question you were printing the names whose age less than 20. So I kept it as it is.